# Solution of two equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading the first chapter of Gilbert Strang's Introduction to linear algebra 5th Edition.

One of the worked examples on vectors is here:
[image]

I wanted to follow the working to also arrive at $c=\frac{2}{3}$ and $d=\frac{1}{3}$ but could not.

My attempt:

$$2c-d-1=-c+2d$$

Express c in terms of d
$$3c-d-1=2d$$
$$3c-1=3d$$
$$3c=3d+1$$
$$c=d+\frac{1}{3}$$

Now rewrite the original equation but replace $c$ with $d+\frac{1}{3}$

$$2 \left(d+\frac{1}{3} \right)-d-1=-d-\frac{1}{3}+2d$$
$$2d+\frac{2}{3}-d-1=-d-\frac{1}{3}+2d$$
$$d+\frac{2}{3}-1=d-\frac{1}{3}$$

That's as far as I got. I cannot get `d` on the left side in the form $d=$ since the d's cancel out.

How can I arrive at $c=\frac{2}{3}$ and $d=\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: "*My attempt*" $\;-\;$ You replaced *two* equations with just *one*. But solving the system $a=0,b=0$ is *not* the same as solving the equation $a=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from: $$c=d+\frac{1}{3}$$
We rewrite the original equation $2c-d=1$ but replace $c$ with $d+\frac{1}{3}$
$$2 \left(d+\frac{1}{3} \right)-d=1$$
$$d=1-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$$
Substituting the value of $d$ into $c=d+\frac{1}{3}$
$$c=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}$$